# Collapse/expand folders in Vivaldi's toolbar bookmarking

Tags: chrome, bookmark

I'm looking for a Chrome extension (or user script) for bookmarking the current tab, which enables collapsing/expanding folder branches to simplify navigation to the desired folder.

**Background**

In Firefox, if you click the toolbar bookmark icon to bookmark the current tab, the drop-down dialog window lets you navigate the bookmark folder structure to select where to save the bookmark.  Each folder there can be expanded, or collapsed to hide its child folder tree.  That makes it easy to find the desired bookmark folder when you have an extensive nested folder structure.

I recently switched to Vivaldi (Chromium based).  Vivaldi can expand and collapse folders in the bookmarks side panel, but not in the dialog window accessed from the toolbar bookmark icon or context menu.  The "bookmark this tab" provision shows the entire bookmarks folder tree in "outline" form (sub-folders indented), with no provision to collapse branches.

With a huge folder tree, you lose the context of where in the tree structure you're looking when the parent folder scrolls out of the window.

Vivaldi uses extensions from the Chrome Store.  A check there identified a few bookmark managers that also let you save the current tab, and one that focuses on bookmarking the current tab via a search box, but doesn't provide a means to see the folder tree.

**Objective**

Ideally, I want to be able to bookmark the current tab by clicking a toolbar icon or context menu, navigating to the desired folder, and clicking a save button.  That navigation would allow collapsing and expanding folders to quickly locate the target folder.  So basically just augmenting the existing bookmarking provision with the ability to collapse and expand folders.  I still want to see the folder structure rather than enter search terms.

Vivaldi already has a built-in bookmarks manager, and buried in its context menu is the ability to save the current tab.  Using that requires the extra steps of opening the side panel and selecting the bookmarks tab, opening a context menu and finding the save option in a long menu, and closing the side panel.  I can add an icon for it to the toolbar, which would save opening and closing the side panel, but it would still be less convenient, and adds the potential to unintentionally open some other bookmark or collection of bookmarks.

So installing a new bookmarks manager that has a similar ability to save the current tab wouldn't add the benefit I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(I noticed a new feature in Vivaldi's bookmark system: in every menu and sub-menu of your bookmark bar, the name of said menu or sub-menu is present and, when you select it, it deploys an "Add active tab" sub-menu.

So, I believe that the logic they implemented to bookmark a page is:

1. deploy the menu/sub-menu where you want to bookmark the page
2. select "Add active tab"

[image]

HTH (even years after the question has been asked!)
Mika